# Echo Custom Taxonomy Field Values Outside the Loop

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy called 'game'; posts have a taxonomy value, i.e. Halo, which then has seven different fields; game_name, game_genre etc.

I'm trying to echo the meta data for a given post's custom taxonomy albeit without much luck.
The small piece of PHP that I tried to use to echo the metadata for the field game_name (designed to be run in a PHP widget) doesn't appear to work. It uses a custom hook created by the plugin [Simple Term Meta](http://www.thinkoomph.com/plugins-modules/wordpress-simple-term-meta/)

```
<?php
global $term;
echo get_term_meta($term->ID, 'game_name', true);
?>
```

Any help in sorting this out would be appreciated, I didn't realise it'd be this complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're trying to use this when viewing a single post? For example, in `single.php`?

If so, you'll need to grab the terms first, *then* grab your meta.

```
global $post;

if ( $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'game' ) ) {

    // $term = $terms[0]; // WRONG! $terms is indexed by term ID!
    $term = array_shift( $terms ); // RIGHT! Will get first term, and remove it from $terms array

    echo get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'game_name', true );

}
```

**UPDATE**

Since the level of code has increased, you'd be much better off wrapping it in a function. Place the following in your `functions.php`;

```
/**
 * Get the game box image for a post.
 * 
 * @param int|object $post
 * @return string
 */
function get_game_box_image( $post = 0 )
{
    if ( ( !$post = get_post( $post ) ) || ( !$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'game' ) ) )
        return ''; // bail

    $term = array_shift( $terms );
    if ( $box = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'game_box', true ) ) {

        $rel = str_replace( content_url(), '', $box );
        if ( is_file( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/' . ltrim( $rel, '/' ) ) )
            return '<div style="text-align: center;"><img src="' . $box . '" alt="" /></div>';
    }

    return '';
}
```

Then to display the game box image, call it like so;

```
<?php echo get_game_box_image(); ?>
```

You can optionally pass a post object or ID argument to the function to get a game box image for a specific post.

Comment: Err no this is being used in a PHP widget in a sidebar.
And unfortunately that still doesn't work :/

Comment: Okaay... What do you get if your `printr($post);` and `printr($terms);`?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function printr() in /home/arranf/co-opreviews.com/wp-content/plugins/linkable-title-html-and-php-widget/linkable-title-html-and-php-widget.php(44) : eval()'d code on line 4

Comment: Wow, mega fail for me - should be `print_r`

Comment: Ok, done the print.
http://pastebin.com/7BibWLXY

Comment: Well there you go. You can see both `$post` and `$terms` are populated, so the meta data function is either failing, or there's nothing to echo. Check the term meta table in your database and cross reference term id 65 to see if any data actually exists.

Comment: The data exists so it's the function that's failing.

Comment: Well I just tested the plugin myself on WordPress 3.1 and everything works fine. Are you sure there is an entry in `wp_termmeta` with `term_id` 65 and `meta_key` 'game_name'?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking at it right now. Could it be using it through the widget that's the issue?

Comment: I think I need a holiday. Use `$term = array_shift( $terms );` instead of `$term = $terms[0]`;` My bad.

Comment: Still without luck.

Comment: Paste what you've currently got.

Comment: `<?php
global $post;

if ( $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'game' ) ) {

    $term = array_shift( $terms ); // first term, but there maybe more
    echo get_term_meta( $term->ID, 'game_name', true );
}
?>`

Comment: Well this is embarassing... use `$term->term_id`, not  `$term->ID`. I need sleep...

Comment: Thank you! It now _finally_ works.
Very much appreciated, I can now finally sleep; and you probably should too...

Comment: Wahey! Sorry for stringing you along! Sleep well :)

Comment: TheDeadMedic, any chance you can help me with a slight modification?

Comment: Whatcha need? It may be worth posting it as a new question so that others can help too.

Comment: I don't think it's anything too radical, but if I'm wrong tell me and I'll post it anew.

I'm trying to modify the code you fixed/remade yesterday. One of the uses I was using it for was to produce the URL of an image inside a HTML image tag. Then I realised that in some browsers if the meta-data wasn't set for that field it'd display a icon rather than just ignoring the HTML tag like it did in Firefox. This is what I came up with, it doesn't work but due to my lack of PHO knowledge I don't know why it doesn't work or how to fix it.
http://pastebin.com/M6fTpBHx

Comment: Yeah, your PHP is a little off! Not to worry! Is `$game_box` an absolute URL? Like `http://example.com/image.jpg` or a relative one, `path/to/image.jpg`? And are these images on the same server or hosted elsewhere?

Comment: Absolute. But they can be easily changed to relative. These images are hosted on the same server.

Comment: Nah should be fine - can you fix your last pastie - I just need to see the code you posted again.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/VQvBzC3U

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: Warning: Wrong parameter count for is_file() in /home/arranf/co-opreviews.com/wp-content/themes/magnifizine-new/functions.php on line 141

Comment: Deleting it removes the issue but then the image HTML still appears even if there is no image to echo.

Comment: Are the images hosted inside the WordPress install directory, or in a directory that is on the same level as (or lower than) WP?

Comment: They're hosted inside the default place /wp-content

Here's an example url: http://www.co-opreviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/gears3box.jpg

Comment: Code in answer revised. Please give it a go!

Comment: As far as I can see that's solved the problem!
Thanks TheDeadMedic!

Comment: Excellent! A vote up would be appreciated for my labour :)

Comment: I would love to but alas my reputation is not high enough as of yet. I'll be sure to drop you one as soon as I can though; I most certainly appreciate the work you've put in here!

Comment: No worries - glad to help. See you around!